# Find the antiderivative of : $\frac{x^4}{\left(x+1\right)^2\left(x^2+1\right)}$

Tags: integration

I'm trying to find the antiderivative of the following function:
$$\frac{x^4}{\left(x+1\right)^2\left(x^2+1\right)}$$
Could you give me some tips as to how to proceed? Long division does not bring me very far, which is why I believe there must be a better way to go about this.
Thanks in advance for any input.

Comment: Partial fractions would be the standard approach -- do you know about them?

Comment: Do you want an answer using long division?

Comment: We cannot directly apply partial fractions, first we need to perform polynomial long division followed by application of linearity and then partial fractions @postmortes.

Comment: @AkashRoy you might want to read lab bhattacharjee's answer :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [Partial Fraction Decomposition](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PartialFractionDecomposition.html),

$$\frac{x^4}{\left(x+1\right)^2\left(x^2+1\right)}=1+\dfrac A{x+1}+\dfrac B{(x+1)^2}+\dfrac{Cx+D}{x^2+1} $$

$1$ as the coefficient of the highest exponent of $x$ in numerator & that of the denominator are same.